# How to fix the below VBA code to create 8 separate PRN files

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with below VBA code - in theory it should create 8 separate prn files, each containing the data from each worksheet. Instead however, I'm getting 8 identical files with data from the first worksheet. I believe the fix is very easy, but i'm basic in VBA unfortunately.
Appreciate your help!

'''

```
Sub Create_PRN()
Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In Worksheets
    shnum = ws.Index
        If shnum > 0 Then
            lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            ActiveSheet.Range("A1:Z" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
            Set wb = Workbooks.Add
            wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial
                wb.Sheets(1).Columns("A").ColumnWidth = 30
                wb.Sheets(1).Columns("B").ColumnWidth = 29
                wb.Sheets(1).Columns("C").ColumnWidth = 8
                wb.Sheets(1).Columns("D").ColumnWidth = 1
                wb.Sheets(1).Columns("E").ColumnWidth = 15
                wb.Sheets(1).Columns("F").ColumnWidth = 10
                wb.Sheets(1).Columns("G").ColumnWidth = 2
                wb.Sheets(1).Columns("H").ColumnWidth = 8
                wb.Sheets(1).Columns("I").ColumnWidth = 5
                wb.Sheets(1).Columns("J").ColumnWidth = 15
                wb.Sheets(1).Columns("K").ColumnWidth = 8
            wb.SaveAs "C:\Users\jsiemiatkowski\OneDrive - RB\Desktop\" & shnum & ".prn", 36
            ' Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show PRNName, 36
            wb.Close
            
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

'''

Comment: Try  adding `ws.select` after `For Each ws In Worksheets`  or better to replace `ActiveSheet.Range("A1:Z" & lr).SpecialCells.....` with `ws.Range("A1:Z" & lr).SpecialCells....` as you are copying activesheet which may be the first sheet, so you are getting prn from the first sheet only.

Comment: Also, replace `lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` with `lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`

Answer (score 0):

### Export Worksheets

- Qualify your object (`.Worksheets, .Range, .Cells, .Rows, .Columns`) references.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CreatePRN()
    
    Dim swb As Workbook ' Source Workbook
    Set swb = ThisWorkbook ' The Workbook Containing This Code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet ' Source Worksheet
    Dim slRow As Long ' Source Last Row
    Dim dwb As Workbook ' Destination Workbook
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    For Each sws In swb.Worksheets
        
        slRow = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        sws.Range("A1:Z" & slRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        
        Set dwb = Workbooks.Add
        With dwb.Worksheets(1)
            .Range("A1").PasteSpecial
            .Columns("A").ColumnWidth = 30
            .Columns("B").ColumnWidth = 29
            .Columns("C").ColumnWidth = 8
            .Columns("D").ColumnWidth = 1
            .Columns("E").ColumnWidth = 15
            .Columns("F").ColumnWidth = 10
            .Columns("G").ColumnWidth = 2
            .Columns("H").ColumnWidth = 8
            .Columns("I").ColumnWidth = 5
            .Columns("J").ColumnWidth = 15
            .Columns("K").ColumnWidth = 8
        End With
        'Application.DisplayAlerts = True ' overwrite without prompt
        dwb.SaveAs "C:\Users\jsiemiatkowski\OneDrive - RB\Desktop\" _
            & sws.Index & ".prn", xlTextPrinter ' 36
        'Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite without prompt
        'Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show PRNName, 36
        dwb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        
    Next sws

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "PRN files created.", vbInformation, "Create PRN"

End Sub
```